# Best way to define a callback and fire it once immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In jQuery, I do stuff like this a lot:

```
$('#myId').bind('myevent', function() { ... }).trigger('myevent');
```

Works great when the selector only finds one element, but I don't want it to fire more than once if there's more than one match.

Is there some way to basically declare an anonymous function and execute it exactly once all in one swoop?

Or do you have to make it non-anonymous (give it a name), pass it in, and call it once manually?

---

For example, I might bind a `.change` event to set of radio buttons. In the callback, I check which one is actually set and then show/hide a div. When the page loads, the div needs to be in the correct state, so I fire the event once and let the JS figure out whether or not it should be shown. But I don't really want it to fire 3 times because I've got 3 radio buttons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`triggerHandler()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/) method instead of the [`trigger()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method.

This will invoke the handler only once, and will not allow the event to bubble or trigger the default behavior.

**From the docs:**

> The .triggerHandler() method behaves
>   similarly to .trigger(), with the
>   following exceptions:
>
> - The .triggerHandler() method does not cause the default behavior of an
>     event to occur (such as a form
>     submission).
> - While .trigger() will operate on all elements matched by the jQuery
>     object, .triggerHandler() only affects
>     the first matched element.
> - Events created with .triggerHandler() do not bubble up the
>     DOM hierarchy; if they are not handled
>     by the target element directly, they
>     do nothing.
> - Instead of returning the jQuery object (to allow chaining),
>     .triggerHandler() returns whatever
>     value was returned by the last handler
>     it caused to be executed. If no
>     handlers are triggered, it returns
>     undefined

Comment: Good stuff, that's the first real use case I've seen for `.triggerHandler()`.

Comment: Had to read that a few times before I understood it..haha. Yes, this sounds like what I want. Awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

If the only issue is when the selector matches more than one element, just use `.first()`:

```
$('some selector').bind('myevent', function()
{
    // ...
}).first().trigger('myevent');
```

It would be very straightforward to turn this into a jQuery plugin, which you'd use just like `.bind()`:

```
$('some selector').bindTrigger('myevent', function () { ... });
```

Plugin code (not tested)

```
;(function ($)
{
    $.fn.bindTrigger = function ()
    {
        this.bind.apply(this, arguments).first().trigger(arguments[0]);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Plugin's a nice idea. Might use that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to define an anonymous function and call it at the same time.

The first is to make the function return itself using the `arguments.callee` value and invoke the function at that place. An example probably makes it clearer:

```
el.bind('myevent', (function() {
  ...;
  return arguments.callee; // return the function
})());
```

The problem with this first approach is, that the function always returns itself. Another approach is to extend the `Function.prototype` with a helper method as in the following example demonstrates:

```
// extend the prototype once somewhere
Function.prototype.invoke = function(){
  this();      // invoke...
  return this; // and return the function
};

// invoke() on an anonymous function now calls the function
// and returns the function instead of the result.
el.bind('myevent', (function(){
  ...
}).invoke());
```

Comment: Should probably mention that `arguments.callee` is deprecated and currently won't work in `"strict mode";`.

Comment: @patrick dw: `Function.arguments.callee` is deprecated, not `arguments.callee`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee